# Multiple MIME types in Activity result launcher Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How can we set multiple mime type in activity result launcher in jetpack compose.

```
val documentPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = contracts, 
onResult = {
          // performing operations with selected file.
        })
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        scope.launch {
        // launching the file picker
          launcher.launch("*/*")
      }

Here i can select all files in the storage. Instead of all files, i need to restrict this into png and pdf. How to acheive this?
```

Comment: Hi could you find any way?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the MIME types to the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/png", "application/pdf"))
```

I'm not 100% sure if those MIME types are correct

Comment: Yea, this can be used with intents, but any idea how to apply the same in compose launcher for activity results?. I didn't see any options to pass intents in the code block i have mentioned.

Comment: You didn't post any code that launches the intent. When you do launch the activity (for result or otherwise, you have to send an intent). If you disagree, please post your code

Answer (score 0):

```
val documentPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = contracts,
    onResult = {
        // performing operations with selected file.
    })
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
scope.launch {
    // launching the file picker
    launcher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf", "image/png"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding `createIntent` function. This code will do it:

```
val documentPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = object : ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() {
            override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: String): Intent {
                return super.createIntent(context, input)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/png", "application/pdf"))
            }
        }, 
    onResult = {
          // performing operations with selected file.
        }
)

val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
scope.launch {
    // launching the file picker
    launcher.launch("*/*")
}
```